# ReactJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I get this error in my ReactJS app that pulls places data.
it seems to me that the error shows when `map()` points to `null`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I could not figure out a way to make a default value

and this is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// This component is for search list view, it render the props places data,
// And handle cilck for place item.
class SearchList extends Component {
    render() {
        // const {places, query, selectPlace} = this.props;
        const {places,query,selectPlace} = this.props;


        return (

        <div className="container">
                <hr/>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Filter"
                        aria-label="Filter Input"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                            query(event.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                    <span className="input-group-addon">
              <i className="fas fa-filter"></i>
            </span>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div style={{maxHeight: '82vh', overflow: 'scroll'}}>
                    <ul className="list-group">
                        {
                            places.map(place => (
                            <li
                                tabIndex="0"
                                key={place.id}
                                className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                                onClick={() => selectPlace(place)}>
                                <span>{place.name}</span>
                            </li>
                        ))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchList;
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you are using this component? If you pass in `undefined` to places by design, you can set a default value like this: `const {places = [],query,selectPlace} = this.props;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can use the [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render your places. Therefore if `places` is undefined the right operand of the and operator (&&) will not be rendered

```
                 <ul className="list-group">
                    {
                       places && places.map(place => (
                        <li
                            tabIndex="0"
                            key={place.id}
                            className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                            onClick={() => selectPlace(place)}>
                            <span>{place.name}</span>
                        </li>
                    ))
                    }
                </ul>
```

Comment: Better to use defaults as described in previous answers.

Comment: @Dan The conditional rendering is the easiest way to go. Besides that, one might forbidden to the child component to set the value that comes from the parent

Answer (score 3):

This happens on the first render since most likely your `places` comes from a resolved Promise somewhere which makes that prop `undefined`. There is a way to fix this, [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops).

```
SearchList.defaultProps = {
    places: [],

}
```

However, if you're passing `places`, like `<SearchList places={this.state.places} />` you need to be sure that `this.state.places` is undefined and *not* `null` since a null value is valid and will override your `defaultProps`. If you want to guard against that then you need to do the conditional rendering.

`places && places.map()`.